Condition for pointwise convergence of simple functions for a Banach space valued function
In real analysis, we have, for a measurable function $f$, extended real/complex valued, it can be pointwise approximated by a sequence of simple functions $s_n$. However, when the function is Banach-valued, the starting point for discussions is a.e convergence by simple functions. I'm wondering, what condition for the Banach space involved is necessary, so that we can mimic the finite-dim situation and always talk about pointwise, rather than a.e. convergence by simple functions. Is reflexivity the answer? Thanks in advance.
Update. I realize what I missed when first posting this question. The context should be

Let $M$ be a complete metric space, and $\Sigma$ a $\sigma$-algebra on $M$ containing the Borel sets. Then, what condition for a Banach space $X$ do we need, so that a function $f: M\to X$ is measurable precisely when it is the pointwise limit of a sequence of simple functions?

Separability is obviously needed, since a sequence of simple functions can only take on countably many values in $X$ and $f(M)$ lies in their closure. But what else do we need?

Separability is a necessary condition.

Look at Vector measures by Diestel and Uhl.

``pointwise everywhere'' vs ''pointwise almost everywhere" has nothing to do with the Banach space but with the measure space under consideration. If the measure space is complete, then one can get away with a.e.
